# Kendo UI type opensource UI free

Tags: kendo-ui, grid, open-source

Can any one tell me is there any thing free and powerful UI like KENDO UI.
Which have same kind of feature like KENDO provide.

Comment: Kendo UI comes in a free flavour already. You don't get access to all the features of the professional version but go do have access to the majority of the suite. I guess it really all depends on what you want in terms of features

Comment: jquery UI ? https://jqueryui.com/

Answer (score -1):

1. http://www.jqwidgets.com/
2. JQgrid
   These are free and opensource